# Pegar o código numa célula e formatar o e-mail usando esse valor (VBA) (EXCEL)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Eu utilizo uma ferramenta da empresa que me dá um número específico para cada cliente. Quando vou enviar e-mail ao cliente, eu preciso que o assunto contenha esse numero.

Com isso em mente, achei uma macro na internet e adaptei um pouquinho para usar conforme minhas necessidades. Atualmente o que eu consegui fazer é um botão que quando clico, ele abre o e-mail já com a mensagem pronta (é um e-mail padrão) minha assinatura e o assunto "MINHA EMPRESA - ".

O que eu preciso, e o motivo desse post, é colocar o número do cliente logo após o nome da minha empresa.

"NOME DA EMPRESA - NÚMERO DO CLIENTE".

Como eu uso uma ferramenta própria, eu copiaria o número do cliente no sistema, colaria na célula A1 (por exemplo) e ao clicar no botão, gostaria que já abrisse o e-mail com o assunto certinho baseado nessa célula.

**Pra exemplificar um pouco melhor:**

*Supondo que o código do cliente seja 123456 e eu insira esse valor na célula A1,
ao clicar no botão gostaria que abrisse um e-mail com o assunto "MINHA EMPRESA - 123456"*

[image: Ao clicar nesse envelope, o e-mail abre conforme a próxima imagem]

[image: Gostaria que o código de cliente abrisse automático depois do "-"]

Comment: Sem o código fica muito amplo para responder, favor criar um [mcve]. Mas o assunto do e-mail normalmente é a propriedade [Subject](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.subject) do mailItem do Outlook.

Comment: Põe o código da macro que você está usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Abaixo um código bem simples para gerar um e-mail no VBA, veja se consegue adaptar.
Vai precisar vários ajustes, supondo que você não vá fazer o e-mail um por um (nesse caso nem precisaria de código...).

abs!

```
Sub email()

Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
olapp.Session.Logon

Set mensagem = olapp.CreateItem(0)
With mensagem
  .To = "destinatários"
  .CC = "com cópia"
  .BCC = "cópia oculta"
  .Subject = "Minha Empresa" & range("A1").Value
  .Body = "corpo do e-mail"
  .display
  .Send
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Consegui arrumar o meu código usando o Range. Obrigado paulo!